# Is there a difference between success and failure of `receipt data` and failure of `trace data`?

Tags: go-ethereum, failed-transaction, transaction-trace

In the case of partial failure of ethereum, Is there a difference between success and failure of `receipt data` and failure of `trace data`?

I found cases where even partial failures are logged as successes.
In the case below, internal tx failed with 'out of gas', but it is recorded as success in receipt.

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4ef4de7db966d5914aa51c3ab85643176d85744016359f7410614ea269df4374

In addition, in case of partial failure, a case in which Ethereum is transmitted has also been confirmed.

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6625d1b8c651239a28042be637d6231cf4e75af8fa9a7267eba62e187237ab8e

In conclusion, I have a question for you below...!

1. What is the difference between failure of 'receipt' and failure of 'trace'?
2. In case of partial failure, can the internal tx that succeeded in the tx transmit ethereum?
3. How is the trace data below recorded in geth?(Is there a place where I can receive the trace data of geth..?)
   https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6625d1b8c651239a28042be637d6231cf4e75af8fa9a7267eba62e187237ab8e